# jQuery eye candy for a WordPress site

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, wordpress

This is a follow-up to [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/24499/code-tidying-up) question my code has evolved since so I'm reposting my question.

What is the best way to tidy this up? How can this be refined? I am finding it's thrashing the layout quite a lot and the scroll function seems to lag.

```
;(function ($, window) {
var main = $("#swab"),
    sbContainer = $("#sb-container"),
    sbContainerDiv = sbContainer.find("div"),
    tblcontents = $('#tblcontents'),
    tblcontentstwo = $('#tblcontents_2'),
    button = $('#wrap_return, .thumb, #tblcontents'),
    slideele = $('.site, .menu-panel'),
    slideele2 = $('.site, .menu-panel_2');



function animate() {
    sbContainerDiv.css({
        "transform": "rotate(0deg)",
            "-webkit-transform": "rotate(0deg)",
            "-ms-transform": "rotate(0deg)",
            "-moz-transform": "rotate(0deg)",
            "-o-transform": "rotate(0deg)"
    });

    main.animate({
        "right": "1%",
            "left": "auto",
            "top": "4px"
    }, "slow");
}

function toggletwo() {

    var toggleStatetwo = true;
    $(tblcontents).on("click", function () {
        if (toggleStatetwo) {
            animate({
                "top": "15%"
            });
            main.fadeOut(1000);
        } else {
            animate();
            main.fadeIn(1000);
        }
        toggleStatetwo = !toggleStatetwo;
    });

}

function toggleone() {
    $(tblcontents).on("click", function () {
        main.stop(true, true).animate();
    });

}

var $window = $(window);
$window.resize(function () {
    if (this.resizeTO) clearTimeout(this.resizeTO);

    this.resizeTO = setTimeout(function () {
        $(this).trigger('resizeEnd');
    }, 500);
});

$window.on('resizeEnd', function () {
    var winWidth = $window.width();

    if (winWidth < 960) {
        toggletwo();
        animate();
    } else {
        toggleone();
    }
});

$(document).scroll(function () {
    animate();
});
var toggleState = true;
$('#toggle_div').on("click", function () {
    if (toggleState) {
        main.animate({
            "right": "50%"
        }, "slow");
    } else {
        main.animate({
            "right": "1%",
                "top": "4px"
        }, "slow");
        main.css("left", "auto");
    }
    toggleState = !toggleState;
});

$(tblcontents).effect("pulsate", {
    times: 100
}, 2000).on('click', function () {
    $(this).effect().stop(true, true);
    $(this).animate({
        "opacity": "1"
    }, "fast");
});
$(button).on("click", function () {
    animate({
        "top": "4px"
    }, "slow");
});
main.draggable()

$(function () {

    sbContainer.swatchbook({
        center: 6,
        angleInc: 20,
        speed: 700,
        easing: 'ease',
        proximity: 120,
        neighbor: 20,
        onLoadAnim: true,
        initclosed: true,
        closeIdx: 11,
        openAt: -1

    });
});

var toggleStatemenu2 = true;
$(tblcontentstwo).on("click", function () {
    if (toggleStatemenu2) {
        $(slideele2).animate({
            top: '+=171'
        }, 458, 'swing', function () {});
    } else {
        $(slideele2).animate({
            top: '-=171'
        }, 458, 'swing', function () {});
    }
    toggleStatemenu2 = !toggleStatemenu2;
});
var toggleStatemenu = true;
$(tblcontents).on("click", function () {
    if (toggleStatemenu) {
        $(slideele).animate({
            left: '+=240'
        }, 458, 'swing', function () {});
    } else {
        $(slideele).animate({
            left: '-=240'
        }, 458, 'swing', function () {});
    }
    toggleStatemenu = !toggleStatemenu;
});

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question:

**Naming**

- JavaScript uses lowerCamelCase variable and function names. ( `tblcontentstwo` -> `TblContentsTwo` or `TabelContents2`
- Some of your prefixes like `sb` are not adding anything. I would drop those prefixes.
- Names like `slideele2` are unfortunate, ideally the name should reflect what is being slided (slid?)

**Comments**

- You have no comments whatsoever, fortunately the code reads well
- Still, in some places, like `sbContainer.swatchbook(`, I have no clue what you are trying to accomplish

**JSHint.com**

- Your code passes all checks, except for 1 semicolon, well done ;)

**Readability**

- You don't use newlines consistently, more specifically you need more newlines in a few spots
- Also your indentation is off in places, I would use a site like http://jsbeautifier.org/

**Don't Repeat Yourself**

- This looks like copy pasted code:

  ```
  var toggleStatemenu2 = true;
  $(tblcontentstwo).on("click", function () {
  if (toggleStatemenu2) {
      $(slideele2).animate({
      top: '+=171'
      }, 458, 'swing', function () {});
  } else {
      $(slideele2).animate({
      top: '-=171'
      }, 458, 'swing', function () {});
  }
  toggleStatemenu2 = !toggleStatemenu2;
  });
  var toggleStatemenu = true;
  $(tblcontents).on("click", function () {
  if (toggleStatemenu) {
      $(slideele).animate({
      left: '+=240'
      }, 458, 'swing', function () {});
  } else {
      $(slideele).animate({
      left: '-=240'
      }, 458, 'swing', function () {});
  }
  toggleStatemenu = !toggleStatemenu;
  });
  ```

  you could try to make a helper function there.

  ```
  var toggleStates = {};

  function createSlider( button, slider, animation1, animation2 ){
    toggleStates[button.id] = true;
    $(button).on("click", function () {
      if (toggleStates[button.id]) {
        $(slider).animate(animation, 458, 'swing', function () {});
      } else {
        $(slider).animate(animation2, 458, 'swing', function () {});
      }
      toggleStates[button.id] = !toggleStates[button.id];
    }
  }
  createSlider(tblcontentstwo, slideele2, {top: '+=171'}, {top: '-=171'} );
  createSlider(tblcontents, slideele, {left: '+=240'}, {left: '-=240'} );
  ```